# Confused by Symfony's file upload documentation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The [last section of Symfony 2.1's file upload documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-the-id-as-the-filename), which provides instructions on how to use the database `id` of a document as its filename, rewrites the `getAbsolutePath()` function:

```
public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
}
```

I am confused. It seems like the `path` property is no longer storing the path, but the extension. What's going on here?

I am trying to alter the class to put uploads in a `uploads/YYYY/MM` folder, and am not sure where I should be putting that. My inclination is to store the `/YYYY/MM` part in the `path` property, but again it seems like it's storing the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is extension in the path property is explained at the top of the code block:

> If you want to use the id as the name of the file, the implementation is slightly different as you need to save the **extension under the path property**, instead of the actual filename

As for where to put `uploads/YYYY/MM` - purely by looking at the documentation example I'd assume that it should go into the `Document::getUploadRootDir()` method.

Assuming that you're storing a `createdAt` field to track when Document was created, the method could look like this:

```
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return sprintf('uploads/%s/%s', $this->createdAt->format('y'), $this->createdAt->format('m'));
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why they're storing the extension under path? Why can't I just store the path in the path variable, instead of a new createdAt property?

Comment: @SamSelikoff what if in one year you want to change the way your path is built? i.e. move everything to a single `uploads` directory? Quite a headache to update whole database. As for `createdAt` - you're not storing it just for the path building, you're storing it to track changes :)